# graphql optimization

Tags: sql, graphql, relay

Everyone!

Is it possible to access info and context for nodedefination. Where I can have abstract syntax tree (AST). I actually need it to optimize my Object (which is node) requests.

For example: if I have the next graphql query:

```
query { node(id:'some_id'){ name, surname, friends{ edges node{ { name,
  surname} }}, posts{edges{ node{ id, text} }}}.
```

So in that case first I have to make SQL query for my person which is node, then I have to ask SQL friends of my person and another SQL query for posts that were made by person. And probably later posts of all friends. That actually is very  expensive. I would love to check fields in request and build a single SQL query.

How would be better to do it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

DataLoader can help you with this, without having to inspect the query. Essentially it enables batching of expensive calls. You write a batch function which is called for each batch, in this function you build a single SQL query of all the individual calls. It's very nice!

In essence it allows you to make naive, to the point, DB requests in your resolvers, and still get the performance benefit of a single DB query. Hope this makes sense?

Read the docs here and give it a try (it's awesome) https://github.com/facebook/dataloader